# How to create master node in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing

I'm very new to cluster/child_process modules in node.js. Can anyone let me know how can we create a master node or how to make a node as master?

Most of the tutorials mention how to verify if a node is Master or Worker (below code), but not how to create master.

EDIT:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
    //cluster.fork(); ----------(2)
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case its a HTTP server
    //cluster.fork();-----------(1)
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    console.log("hello worldd");
    res.end("hello worldd\n");
  }).listen(8000);
}
```

EDIT: How can I create proper child process that runs continuously. If I create new process using cluster.fork like (1) in above code, the worker processes are getting created and destroyed immediately. If I create workers like (2) in above code, it will go into infinite loop of process death and creation. If the above example is not clear, please provide any code or link that demonstrates proper working example of creating child process and processing multiple requests across different processes concurrently.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually *create* a master. When you call `cluster.fork`, it creates a child process. The master still exists. Both child and master operate on the same code base, and is distinguished based on the `cluster.isMaster`.

Edit:

If you want to create a service/webserver on port `8000`. You should do it as you showed in (2). Except, for your case, it will go in an infinite loop because you are doing it on 'exit' event without really checking why it 'exited'. You can avoid by checking `worker.suicide`

For instance:

```
if(cluster.isMaster) {
  for(var i = 0; i< numCpus; i++)
     cluster.fork();

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
    if(worker.suicide) //do nothing
    else cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  // create server && listen on 8000
  // no need to involve cluster here.
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {}).listen(8000);
}
```

Edited: Sample gist: https://gist.github.com/limianwang/55e8a0b6ca816e024358

Take a read at:

http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_suicide

Comment: Thanks for your input. I get your point, which leads me to another question, which I updated in the question. Please have a look at it and provide your insight.

Comment: You mean to say, (1) is in correct place to create new child process and (2) will work as expected if suicide/kill check is done, right?

Comment: No. You only call `cluster.fork` in the _master_ never in the worker. Worker should only be concerned about the processing of incoming requests etc. You got everything right, except the 'exit' event handling. So basically, (1) is not need to be there.

Comment: I get your point. But If I put cluster.fork only inside the master, then my code never goes inside the master, hence there is no child node forking.

Comment: @user3366706 That is impossible. I created a gist look at it, and I have also provided the output: https://gist.github.com/limianwang/55e8a0b6ca816e024358

Answer (score 1):

cluster.fork() creates a child process that does not exit.  Calling res.end() does not exit the child, it waits and listens for more connections.

Case (2) above will only occur if the child called process.exit() or was killed, in which case the master would want to replace the lost worker process, but it's not a tight loop.